# Unable to build in Android in vscode

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, visual-studio-code

> Checking build Searching for devices... Launch failed: ADBSocket Socket connect failed. connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:5037. Ensure any instances of Android Studio are closed.

I uninstalled Android studio. Even I checked and port 5037 is free.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have the same error. I fixed the issue with the following:

1. On terminal: Run command **`adb devices`**

*It showed output like this:

> - daemon not running. starting it now on port 5037 *
> - daemon started successfully
> - List of devices attached  9e0a8524  unauthorized
>   [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/MXtY7.png

2. Checking adb devices launched a pop up screen on my mobile to **allow access**. I **clicked Allow(Ok) and that's it!**

**Hope it helps!**