# Running Android App in Visual Studio Code with Emulator

Tags: android, react-native, android-studio, visual-studio-code

I am developing a React Native application which is integrated with Android. It is easier for me to be developing just using Visual Studio Code for React Native and Java in the same place. Currently, I am developing React Native in Visual Studio Code and Android (Java) in Android Studio.

I would like to open just Visual Studio Code and develop React Native and Android (Java) in one place. I have gone through the following steps:

1.- Install Android extension in Visual Studio Code.

2.- Created a launch.json" file, selected type "Android" in the drop down text field to populate automatically configuration.

3.- Edited configuration to point to correct location for `app-dev-debug.apk` file in apkFile and update appSrcRoot with the correct path. In name, I changed the value to the name of the project.

4.- Having Android Studio closed and not having the emulator started, I clicked on Run and Debug Icon (green triangle) and got the following error:

```
Searching for devices...
Launch failed: ADBSocket Socket connect failed. connect ECONNREFUSED ::1:5037.
Ensure any instances of Android Studio are closed.
```

5.- In cmd, under the root path of react native project listed the devices:

```
PS C:\ReactNativeProject> adb devices
List of devices attached
```

6.- In cmd, under C:/Users/john/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/tools/bin> listed my configured emulators:

```
emulator -list-avds 
Pixel_XL_API_33
```

7.- Started the emulator under tools directory:

```
cd ..
emulator -avd Pixel_XL_API_33
INFO    | Storing crashdata in: C:\Users\john\AppData\Local\Temp\\AndroidEmulator\emu-crash.db, detection is enabled
INFO    | Duplicate loglines will be removed, if you wish to see each indiviudal line launch with the -log-nofilter flag.
INFO    | IPv4 server found: 142.34.239.5
ANGLE: D3D11: rx::Renderer11::generateConfigs
INFO    |
INFO    |  (3x)
INFO    | Crash reports will be automatically uploaded to: https://clients2.google.com/cr/report
INFO    | added library vulkan-1.dll
INFO    | Sending adb public key [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 @unknown]
INFO    |
WHPX on Windows 10.0.19045 detected.
Windows Hypervisor Platform accelerator is operational
WARNING | *** No gRPC protection active, consider launching with the -grpc-use-jwt flag.***
INFO    | Started GRPC server at 127.0.0.1:8554, security: Local, auth: none
INFO    | Advertising in: C:\Users\john\AppData\Local\Temp\avd\running\pid_25960.ini
INFO    | Setting display: 0 configuration to: 1440x2560, dpi: 560x560
INFO    |
```

8.- In cmd, under my project directory I can list the emulators again:

```
PS C:\ReactNativeProject> adb devices
List of devices attached
emulator-5554   device
```

Now I have an emulator indicating port 5554.

9.- Click again Run and Debug on VSC (green triangle) and get the same in debug console:

```
Searching for devices...
Launch failed: ADBSocket Socket connect failed. connect ECONNREFUSED ::1:5037.
Ensure any instances of Android Studio are closed.
```

Is something I can be missing to run my android application from Visual Studio Code?

Thanks for your advice :)

Comment: Go to this link : https://stackoverflow.com/a/66773395/22576359 Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks @sina, this link works when connecting physical android device. I am looking for using the emulator :)